# understanding time space complexity with respect to JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux, time-complexity

So the scenario is that i have a object with a lot of key value pairs in it and is nested too. I need to access these key value pairs frequently but not all at the same time.
For Example:
if i have a object with 10 key value pairs i might only use 4 of them more frequently.

I thought of two approach to handle this situation:

1. I would iterate over the complete object once and fetch every single key value pair and store each of them separately in reduxe store.
2. Instead of storing each and every key pair separately i would keep the object as it is and only fetch the required key value pair from object using **Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(customObject, 'key')**.

**Time space complexity analysis:**

1. In the first approach i will be using extra space in redux store as i would be storing the complete object itself and every key value pair separately. This give me a time complexity of **O(N)** because i will be iterating over the complete object and i will also be **using extra space**.
2. In the second approach i would only be storing the main object in store and on the need basis will be fetching the key value pair. This give me time complexity of **O(1)** as the **hasOwnProperty()** is a key lookup method and i am **not using extra space for storage**.

My question is which approach should i prefer? In my opinion second approach is better.

Comment: Seems like you are going to write code for some microchip with very little memory and processing power. In your reudux kind of scenario, it does not matter even if you have millions of objects. Objects keys are hashed and you can access in O(1), you don't need to create a small sub object with fewer keys

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz i understand what you are saying, but  a colleague of mine is not ready to understand, so i just wanted to have more clarity on how objects work in javascript and to brush up on the concept of time and space complexity. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share more code for both approaches?